# VS Code issue: Getting horizontal bars on graph plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I've been using VS Code for my projects for a while. But now I'm getting this erroneous graph with horizontal bars that are overlapping some other graph. This has started happening recently, and I don't know what changed.

Graph 1: errorful graph

[image]

```py
# creating a visual to see the brands that are most consumed by mainstream - young singles/couple

young_mainstream = purchases.loc[purchases['LIFESTAGE'] == 'YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES']
young_mainstream = young_mainstream.loc[young_mainstream['MEMBER_TYPE'] == 'Mainstream']

ax = young_mainstream['BRAND_NAME'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = True).plot.barh(figsize = (10, 5))
ax.set_xlabel('Number of packets purchased')
ax.set_ylabel('Brand Name')
plt.show()
```

Graph 2: Another graph that's messed up:
[image]

```
# Plot a histogram to visualise distribution of brand names 

plt.figure(facecolor = 'w')
plt.bar(transactions['BRAND_NAME'], transactions['PROD_QTY'])
plt.xlabel('Brand Name')
plt.ylabel('Quantity')
plt.show()
```

Desired output:

Graph 1: [image]

I've tried looking around for VS Code display settings that could possibly cause this, but haven't found anything substantial.

Comment: Well, you are calling the `barh` method, which creates a horizontal bar plot. I'm assuming there is more code that would explain why it looks how it does.

Comment: The goal plot is supposed to be a `barh` graph only

Comment: Right, but your question says that the horizontal bars are "erroneous" and "overlapping the actual graph" when you want horizontal bars. As I said in my previous comment, there is probably some more code being run that is resulting in the wrong plot, but without that code, we cannot tell you what the issue is.

Comment: Right, I myself was a bit confused. I'll make the necessary changes.

Comment: Try creating a new Axes first before plotting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)